# Unable to use ST_Intersects on geometry field

Tags: gis, postgis, sharpmap

I have converted the Personal Geodatabase of ESRI (*.mdb file) into the PostGIS enabled PostgreSQL database using ***FWTools***. On which I get my **geometry** field named as **wkb_geometry** as follows

```
wkb_geometry geometry(Geometry, 3148),
```

While querying the database using **ST_Intersects** on where I get following error

**SQL**

```
SELECT <other fields>, 
"wkb_geometry" AS "_smtmp_" FROM parcel WHERE  <condition>  
AND ST_Intersects(((E'\\001\\003\\000\\000 L\\014\\000\\000\\001\\000\\000\\000\\005\\000\\000\\000\\020\\2625\\334i\\032\\034A\\273n\\256E\\033\\340GA\\020\\2625\\334i\\032\\034A\\017\\261\\014\\353\\037\\340GA\\262\\304\\047\\007\\217\\032\\034A\\017\\261\\014\\353\\037\\340GA\\262\\304\\047\\007\\217\\032\\034A\\273n\\256E\\033\\340GA\\020\\2625\\334i\\032\\034A\\273n\\256E\\033\\340GA')) 
                    ,"wkb_geometry")
```

**Error**

> ERROR:  parse error - invalid geometry
>   LINE 1: ... parcel WHERE  parcelno < 50  AND ST_Intersects(((E'\001\0...
>   HINT:  "\0" <-- parse error at position 2 within geometry
>
> ERROR: parse error - invalid geometry
>   SQL state: XX000
>   Hint: "\0" <-- parse error at position 2 within geometry
>   Character: 245

I am using SharpMap in front end.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is not with the geometry field, but with the query.

You should use the ST_GeomFromEWKB function like this

```
SELECT <other fields>, 
"wkb_geometry" AS "_smtmp_" FROM parcel WHERE  <condition>  
AND ST_Intersects(ST_GeomFromEWKB(E'\\001\\003\\000\\000 L\\014\\000\\000\\001\\000\\000\\000\\005\\000\\000\\000\\020\\2625\\334i\\032\\034A\\273n\\256E\\033\\340GA\\020\\2625\\334i\\032\\034A\\017\\261\\014\\353\\037\\340GA\\262\\304\\047\\007\\217\\032\\034A\\017\\261\\014\\353\\037\\340GA\\262\\304\\047\\007\\217\\032\\034A\\273n\\256E\\033\\340GA\\020\\2625\\334i\\032\\034A\\273n\\256E\\033\\340GA') 
                    ,"wkb_geometry")
```

Comment: I will try and let you know and mark this as resolved.